# Upload a file whose field styling display is None

Tags: python, file-upload, selenium

I have a file field whose display is None , I want to upload a file into it using selenium python bindings

I tried this but its not working

```
driver.find_element_by_id("IdOfInputTypeFile").send_keys(os.getcwd()+"/image.png")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('id_cv_upload').style.display='block';")
```

Try this basically `execute_script` is the command for python to run a javascript as there is no pythonic way to deal with css so u have to execute a javascript to do that.